# INNER JOIN condition not working

Tags: sql, inner-join, aggregate-functions

Suppose we have table as :

```
EMPNO   ENAME   DEPTNO
------  ------  ----------
7369    SMITH   20
7499    ALLEN   30
7654    MARTIN  30
7788    SCOTT   20
7839    KING    10
7900    JAMES   30
```

How can we find all those employees who work in the same deptno as of SCOTT ?
I tried as follows :

```
SELECT e.ename FROM employee e INNER JOIN employee m ON e.deptno=m.deptno;
```

, but the result isn't correct.

Comment: Parado solution is working?  Vote upp and set it as your prefered answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add one more condition as below

```
SELECT e.ename 
FROM employee e 
INNER JOIN employee m ON e.deptno=m.deptno
                      AND m.ENAME = 'SCOTT'
WHERE m.ENAME <> 'SCOTT'; -- exclude scott
```

You can also try with a subquery

```
SELECT e.ename 
FROM employee e
WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1
   FROM employee M
   WHERE  M.ENAME = 'SCOTT'
   and E.deptno=M.deptno        
)
AND  m.ENAME <> 'SCOTT'; -- exclude scott;
```

Comment: but one of my friend mailed me the solution as : SELECT e.ename FROM employee e INNER JOIN employee m ON e.deptno=m.deptno AND m.ename = ‘SCOTT’ AND e.ename<>’SCOTT’; What does this '<>' operator mean ?

Comment: @RubbalBhusri so `scott` will not be included in the list of result.